# Pydot - store nodes in list - unhashable type: 'list' error

Tags: python, list, pydot

I'm using pydot to generate a graph from a list of strings

```
graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph')
node_list = []
for i in xrange(0, len(string_list)):
    node_list.append(pydot.Node(string_list[i]))
    graph.add_node(node_list[-1])
    for j in (0,len(string_list)):
        graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(node_list[i], node_list[j], label=matrix[i,j]))
```

but I get the following error in the add_node line:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You sure `graph.add_node(node_list[-1])` causes the error? Add the full traceback

Comment: Are you sure that matrix[i,j] is a valid way to access elements from whatever this matrix object is?

Comment: Yes, the traceback is "graph.add_node(node_list[-1])", "node = self.get_node(graph_node.get_name())", "if self.obj_dict['nodes'].has_key(name):"

Comment: what do you see if you add a `print(node_list[-1])`before the add_node line

Comment: Ah you're right... node_list is a list of lists. Solved, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list in `string_list`, the error can be reproduced with:

```
graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph')

node_a = pydot.Node(["Node A"])

graph.add_node(node_a)
```